# MarkLogic Corb error: Could not find or load main class

Tags: marklogic-10, marklogic-corb

When I run a corb script on Linux I get:

> Error: Could not find or load main class com.marklogic.developer.corb.Manager.

I resolved this error when I ran the CoRB job from my Windows laptop (MarkLogic was running on a separate Linux server), however I cannot resolve it when running it on the Linux server hosting MarkLogic server (.cmd was converted to .sh).

When the bash/java command is run the directory reference is not where the .sh file is being run from at the command line ($HOME/corb) ?

Any ideas on the cause/solution?

#### Setup

Linux 7.9 / MarkLogic 10.3 / openjdk version "1.8.0_275"
Corb => $HOME/corb / MarkLogic XCC => $HOME/MarkXCC.java-10.0.10

#### Sample code

runme.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
java  -cp "$HOME/corb/marklogic-corb-2.5.4.jar:$HOME/MarkXCC.java-10.0.10/lib/marklogic-xcc-10.0.10.jar" -DOPTIONS-FILE=journallistingcorb.properties com.marklogic.developer.corb.Manager
```

#### Command used

```
cd $HOME/corb
bash runme.sh
```

#### Response

```
Error: Could not find or load main class com.marklogic.developer.corb.Manager
```

I have changed the corb reference forms "$HOME/corb/marklogic-corb-2.5.4.jar" to "marklogic-corb-2.5.4.jar"
and also swapping the positions of the corb and xcc '.jar' references, and include/exclude the '-server' parameter (in front of '-cp').

Answer (score 0):

When you see that message, it means that the CoRB jar isn't on your classpath.

Either the file path is wrong, or you don't have read permissions to "see" the jar.

Comment: The same error message is returned with these changes.          Set jar permissions to 764 but  
Run "bash runme.sh" from /corb in two syntax variants,
`java  -cp "$Home/corb/marklogic-corb-2.5.4.jar:$Home/MarkXCC.java-10.0.10/lib/marklogic-xcc-10.0.10.jar"...`
`java  -cp "marklogic-corb-2.5.4.jar:$Home/MarkXCC.java-10.0.10/lib/marklogic-xcc-10.0.10.jar"...`
Run "bash runme.sh" from /home with this syntax,
`java  -cp "corb/corb/marklogic-corb-2.5.4.jar:MarkXCC.java-10.0.10/lib/marklogic-xcc-10.0.10.jar" ...`
Setting permissions to 777, and using "sudo bash runme.sh", had no effect.

Comment: is it possible that the jar is mangled? Like, if you FTPed it in ascii mode instead of binary? Can you verify that it's good by running `zipinfo $Home/corb/marklogic-corb-2.5.4.jar`?

Comment: I was coming to the same conclusion. zipinfo doesn't show any errors and I've just downloaded corb 2.5.3 (zipinfo also shows no errors) and the error is the same.

Comment: Same issue with corb 2.3.2. So reverting to using a windows server.